# Guzzle give me weird json response

Tags: php, post, request, guzzle

I'm currently using Guzzle to make a post request and send some parameters.

**Here's my code:**

```
$client = new Client();
$url = $this->my_url;

$client->setSslVerification(false,false,0);
$request = $client->post($url,null,array(
                            "param1" => $param1,
                            'param2' => $param2
                        ));

$postBody = $request->getBody();
$response = $client->send($request);
$body = $response->getBody();

echo $body;
```

I get this return (JSON) when I'm doing the echo:

```
int 1
{"Response":true}
```

And of course, I can't do a `json_decode` on it.
I don't understand why I can't do it and why I have this `"int 1"` before it.

Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest that the site you're calling is var_dump()ing some value before generating the json response.... their issue that they need to fix: perhaps you should tell them

Comment: I wrote the url calling side, and anyway i return a array which is encapsulated in a json_encode. Sure that any var_dump is applied on this side.

Comment: Well that `int 1` isn't part of the json_encoded response.... I suspect you still have some debug code in there.... Guzzle isn't arbitrarily injecting it, so it's somewhere in your code

Comment: @MarkBaker you were right !

 I just see that I had a hiding var_dump()ing in the other side in an other class ! 

Many thanks for your suggestion !